# Writing a LEFT JOIN With error

Tags: php, sql, drupal-modules

I have the following raw SQL:

```
    SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type
    FROM 
    {node} node
    LEFT JOIN {field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node} field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node ON node.nid = field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.commerce_node_checkout_node_target_id AND (field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.entity_type = 'commerce_line_item' AND field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.deleted = '0')
    LEFT JOIN {commerce_line_item} commerce_node_checkout_node_node ON field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.entity_id = commerce_node_checkout_node_node.line_item_id
    WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('myproducts')) ))
    LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

I have a module that I need to add this query to, list of user products with body field in drupal commerce...

This is what I've added to $query.

```
    $query = db_select('{node}', 'node');
    $query->fields('node', array('title', 'nid', 'created'));
    $query->leftJoin('{field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node}', 'field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node', 'node.nid = field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.commerce_node_checkout_node_target_id AND (field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.entity_type = 'commerce_line_item' AND field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.deleted = '0')');
    $query->leftJoin('{commerce_line_item}', 'commerce_node_checkout_node_node', 'field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.entity_id = commerce_node_checkout_node_node.line_item_id');
    $query->condition('node.status', 1);
    $query->condition('node.type', array(myproducts), 'IN');
    $query->range(0, 5);
    $result = $query->execute();
```

How do i write code with no error ?

Answer (score 0):

You had some syntax errors. I resolved them and rewrite your query in true way. check it and inform me about the result

I suggest taking a look at [db_select documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x) and **Strongly recommend write errors in question be to get better answers dadash**

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('title', 'nid', 'created'));
$query->leftJoin('field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node', 'fcn', 'n.nid = fcn.commerce_node_checkout_node_target_id');
$query->leftJoin('commerce_line_item', 'cli', 'fcn.entity_id = cli.line_item_id');
$query->condition('fcn.entity_type', 'commerce_line_item');
$query->condition('fcn.deleted', 0);
$query->condition('n.status', 1);
$query->condition('n.type', array($myproducts), 'IN');
$query->range(0, 5);
$result = $query->execute();
```